# Facebook like Button generator not working on specific URL´s

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, share

I searched several question concerning the facebook like button, but this does not solve my problem with some urls. I tried to implement a like button with this url:
https://www.facebook.com/behindthemask.divestories/videos/478081905732207/
I used the generator and even the generator does not preview the like button. I am a little confused, because this is a facebook url.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to implement a like button with this url: https://www.facebook.com/behindthemask.divestories/videos/478081905732207/  […]
>   I am a little confused, because this is a facebook url.

You can not use the Like button for this kind of object (videos, posts, photos) directly on Facebook.
The Like button can like Facebook Pages, or external URLs (Open Graph objects).

If you want your users to be able to like FB objects such as a video, you need to implement it via API – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/object/likes#publish
That will require that you implement FB Login, and that users login to your app before they can post a like.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#configurator

If it doesn't, it helps to show us a piece of your code in order to analyse what went wrong.

Comment: The code I used was just the link in the generator:`<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/behindthemask.divestories/videos/478081905732207/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>`